# Dot delimited parsing with awk

Tags: awk, sh

I have an output from a command that looks like the following:

```
hw.sensors.cpu0.temp0=39.00 degC
hw.sensors.acpitz0.temp0=27.80 degC (zone temperature)
```

The desired `awk` output is as follows:

```
# TYPE hw_sensors gauge
hw_sensors{sensor="cpu0" reading="temp0"} 39
hw_sensors{sensor="acpitz0" reading="temp0"} 27
```

My thinking at the moment is a bit messy (I'm no `awk` guru !), so my effort so far looks like this:

```
sysctl hw.sensors | fgrep temp0 | sed 's/\./_/g' | awk '{FS="="; print "# TYPE "$1" gauge\n"$1" "$2}' | sed -E 's/_[[:digit:]]{1,2}.*$//g'
```

I guess I could continue with more pipes, but that is most likely the wrong method !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that testing for temp0 really is necessary and that your input can contain multiple types of report:

```
sysctl hw.sensors |
awk -F'[.=]' '
    !/temp0/ { next }
    { type = $1 "_" $2 }
    !doneHdr[type]++ { printf "# TYPE %s gauge\n", type }
    { printf "%s{sensor=\"%s\" reading=\"%s\"} %d\n", type, $3, $4, $5 }
'
# TYPE hw_sensors gauge
hw_sensors{sensor="cpu0" reading="temp0"} 39
hw_sensors{sensor="acpitz0" reading="temp0"} 27
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be the easiest for you and most adaptable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="="}'
     {key=$1; value=$2}
     {split(key,k,/[.]/)}
     {split(value,v)}
     {print k[1]"_"k[2]"{sensor=\042" k[3] "\042 reading=\042"k[4]"\042}",v[1]}'
```

This works in the following way:

1. split each line in a key and value pair:

   ```
   line: hw.sensors.cpu0.temp0=39.00 degC
   => key=hw.sensors.cpu0.temp0
   => value=39.00 degC
   ```
2. split the key in subparts based on the dot as delitimer, store the parts in array `k`:

   ```
   key=hw.sensors.cpu0.temp0
   split(key,k,/[.]/)
   => k=(hw,sensor,cpu0,temp0)
   ```
3. split the value in subparts based on a blank as delimiter, sotre the parts in array v:

   ```
   value=39.00 degC
   split(value,v)
   => k=(39.00,degC)
   ```
4. Reassemble the parts the way you like:

   ```
   print k[1]"_"k[2]"{sensor=\042" k[3] "\042 reading=\042"k[4]"\042}",v[1]
   ```

This method is very flexible, as you can now put conditions on the parts to determine the reassembling rule: example:

```
(k[2]=="sensor"){ print k[1]"_"k[2]"{sensor=\042" k[3] "\042 reading=\042"k[4]"\042}",v[1] }
(k[2]=="dog") { print "This dog is",v[1], "cm long" }
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `.` and `=` as field separator using `awk`, use column `3,4,5`

```
sysctl hw.sensors | awk -F'[.=]' -v fmt='hw_sensors{sensor="%s" reading="%s"} %d\n' '/temp0/{ printf(fmt,$3,$4,$5) }'
```

**Better Readable version**

```
sysctl hw.sensors | \
awk -F'[.=]' -v fmt='hw_sensors{sensor="%s" reading="%s"} %d\n' '
/temp0/{ 
     printf(fmt,$3,$4,$5) 
}'
```

**Explanation**

- `-F'[.=]'` set field separator

```
hw.sensors.cpu0.temp0=39.00 degC
^    ^       ^    ^    ^  ^
col1 col2   col3 col4 col5 col6
```

- `-v fmt='hw_sensors{sensor="%s" reading="%s"} %d\n'` variable `fmt` contains format string, similar to `c/c++`,
- `/temp0/{` search for line/row/records contains `temp0`
- `printf(fmt,$3,$4,$5)` print your fields finally

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[.=]' -v s1="\"" '{print $1"_"$2"{"$2"="s1 $3 s1 " reading="s1 $4 s1 "} " $5+0}' Input_file
```